# How to send little BTC coin in Bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet, sending, bitcoin-wallet-app

I use [bitcoin wallet](https://www.bitcoin.com/) (find here)

I tried to send 32$ (All of them) to Binanace OR my Trust wallet or etc , but appear below error :

[image]

Comment: You should pay fees, fees cant be 0.

Comment: Also try using better wallets https://bitcoinwallet.guide

Comment: Careful, bitcoin,com is run by scammers! Get your coins out of there ASAP and never look back.

Comment: @Зелёный how to set fee? I choose BTC network fee policy is **Economy** , other wallet automatic handle pay fee .

Comment: Maybe it can't add fees because the amount you set is maximum. Unfortunately there's no "send all" option in bitcoin.com wallet, so you could instead enter the seed to a different wallet to send all your coins.

Comment: Chapter 2 :-) https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch02.asciidoc